# Voice Recognition and Text to Speech

Tags: android

I want to develop an application which implements voice recognition,and after that implements text to speech using text to speech Engine.I posted the code bellow. I use two buttons and a list view.One button is used for voice recognition, another one is used for text to speech, and the list view is used for both (first in the list view is posted the result of voice recognition, and then the application will read back the words from the list view). When I touch the button for the voice recognition the words are posted in my list view, but the problem is that when I  press the button for text to speech  the application doesn't read back the words from the list view and in my logcat when I press this button I don't receive any information about this.
Here is my program:

```
package rtv.rtv.rtv;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.util.Log;

public class VoiceRecTextSpeech extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnInitListener {
    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private ListView mList;

    private Button speakBtn = null;
    private static final int REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK = 0;
    private static final String TAG = "TTS Demo";
    private TextToSpeech mTts;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Button and ListView for Voice Recognition
        Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        //Button for Text to Speech
        speakBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speak);

        // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
        if (activities.size() != 0) {
            speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {
            speakButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
        }

        // Check to be sure that TTS exists and is okay to use
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK);
    }


        //Handle the click on the start recognition button and on text to speech button

        public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_speak:
            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
            break;
        case R.id.speak:
            mTts.speak(mList.toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            break;

        }
        }

        //Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity

        private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
            startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        // Handle the results 

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
                ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                        RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        matches));
            }

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK) {
                switch (resultCode) {
                case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS:
                    // TTS is up and running
                    mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Pico is installed okay");
                    break;
                case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_BAD_DATA:
                case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_DATA:
                case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_VOLUME:
                    // missing data, install it
                    Log.v(TAG, "Need language stuff: " + resultCode);
                    Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                    installIntent.setAction(
                            TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                    startActivity(installIntent);
                    break;
                case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FAIL:
                default:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Got a failure. TTS apparently not available");
                }
            }
            else {
                // Got something else
            }

        }

         @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                // Now that the TTS engine is ready, we enable the button
                if( status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    speakBtn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onPause()
            {
                super.onPause();
                // if we're losing focus, stop talking
                if( mTts != null)
                    mTts.stop();
            }
            @Override
            public void onDestroy()
            {
                super.onDestroy();
                mTts.shutdown();
            }
}
```

Here is the main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:id="@+id/speak"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false" android:text="Text To Speech" android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_speak"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Speak for Voice Recognition"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks !

Comment: What happens, anything in Logcat?

Answer (score 1):

Your TTS Button has no onClickListener() registered. Therefore your code starting TTS is never called. Are you sure you want to convert the ListView to a String and pass it to the TTS engine? More likely you want to convert the data in the adapter of the ListView to a String.

Answer (score 1):

Even if status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS passes, it could be that the language data is not supported.

Sometime after onInit() you need to execute some code that looks like this:

```
public void onInit(Context context, TextToSpeech tts, Locale forLocale)
{
    Locale defaultOrPassedIn = forLocale;
    if (forLocale == null)
    {
        defaultOrPassedIn = Locale.getDefault();
    }
    // check if language is available
    switch (tts.isLanguageAvailable(defaultOrPassedIn))
    {
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE:
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE:
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE:
            tts.setLanguage(defaultOrPassedIn);
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA:
            Log.d(TAG, "MISSING_DATA");
            // check if waiting....
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent
                    .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            context.startActivity(installIntent);
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            Log.d(TAG, "NOT SUPPORTED");
            // report failure to the user
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you insure that its actually receiving results?

As in your adapter has some elements in it? Debug from the starting points **ALWAYS**.